# How to show floats only 2 number after point in delphi?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi programming i want to show 13.45 instead of 13.45876 ,would you please help me?
I mean i want to manage the show way of a float value.
with best regards.

Comment: 10 seconds of internet search revealed for example: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FormatFloat

Comment: You mean 13.46 right? You want to round or truncate?

Comment: Apalling selection of dupe!!

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous options including:

- [`FormatFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat)
- [`FloatToStrF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStrF)
- [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format)

To illustrate:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  d: Double = 13.45876;

begin
  Writeln(FormatFloat('0.00', d));
  Writeln(FloatToStrF(d, ffFixed, 16, 2));
  Writeln(Format('%.2f', [d]));
end.
```

**Output**

```
13.46
13.46
13.46
```

Comment: tnx alot for your help.

Comment: I always get into trouble for asking "why", but is there a practical reason for the three different functions or are any deprecated? With a general Format function I'm unclear why you'd need the other two.

Comment: @alcalde I don't actually know why. I think if you dig deep enough you'll find that there are more than 3!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var
 d: double;
begin
  d:=13.45876 ;
  Edit1.Text:=FormatFloat('0.00',d);   //save value
end;
```